# What are the actual linguistic similarities between Russian and Belarusian?

Tags: грамматика, other-languages, slavic, belorussian

I lived in Belarus for some time, and my wife is from there. We spoke only Russian while in the country, but most signs, public transportation announcements ("next stop", etc.) and documents were in the Belarusian language.

I've learned *very* basic amounts of Belarusian, and I'm wondering what the linguistic similarity (language family, etc) is between it and the Russian language. It seems to me to be more mutually understandable with Polish, but it has quite a few "Russian-sounding" words as well as a seemingly similar grammatical structure.

Answer (score 12):

I highly doubt that Belorussian mutually understandable with Polish. On the other hand it is quite mutually understandable with Russian, a little more so than Ukrainian.

The relation is following: Belorussian, Russian, Ukrainian and Rusyn belong to East Slavic branch of Slavic languages, with Belorussian, Rusyn and Ukrainian belonging to Ruthenian subbranch. So Belorussian is closer to Ukrainian than to Russian.

All three are quite far from Polish (the later being a West Slavic language), but more than that, I would say Polish is less similar to East Slavic compared to other West Slavic languages (Chech, Slovak for example) both in phonology and spelling.

Comment: It's interesting you say that you doubt it is mutually intelligible with Polish - while in Białystok, my wife would speak Belarusian and they would respond in Polish :)

Comment: @jaska this depends on what she said actually and also whether they had any exposure to Belorussian before as a language of their geographical neighbours (and possibly a substantial ethnic minority in the city).

Comment: but wouldn't my wife need to have had some exposure to Polish as well, to be able to understand their responses?

Comment: @jaska may be, this depends on what things she was asking, actually.

Comment: Pretty basic things - how to get around, where/when to find bus stops, buying stuff in stores, etc. Whatever we'd need for a semi-tourist week's stay in the city (as well as another week we spent in Warsaw)

Also, sorry, for some reason it's not letting me "@" your name at the beginning of my comments.

Comment: @Anixx, are you seriously saying Czech is phonologically closer to East Slavic languages (any of them) than Polish? Do you actually know anything about Czech? Somehow this level of competence doesn't surprise me, coming from someone who finds no problem with randomly insulting people.

Comment: @jaska You wrote: _‘sorry, for some reason it's not letting me "@" your name at the beginning of my comments’._ You do not need, for instance, `@John` in comment to John’s answer, he will get notification even without it. ⁂ As for your question, you should also note, that Bielorussian and Ukrainian have quite a lot of words loaned from Polish (and most of them were by turn borrowed from German). You may encounter them even among the most everyday vocabulary. E. g. biel. _дзякуй_ ‘thanks’ ← pol. _dzięk_ ← mid.-low-germ. _dank_.

Comment: @NikolayErshov As far as I understand, Anixx did not say, what you are attributing to her/him. (S)he said, (s)he believe that it’s more resemblance between, say, Bielorussian and Czech in phonetics than between Bielorussian and Polish. That’s pretty subjective thing and I in person would affirm that, but you definitely have a sort of negative personal experience with her/him, that does not allow you to react on her/his answers impartially :-)

Comment: @NikolayErshov Кстати, добро пожаловать на Russian.SE. Пожалуйста, не принимайте близко к сердцу, если кто-нибудь скажет что-то грубое. Некоторые участники (я, например) довольно посредственно владеют английским и могут ляпнуть что-нибудь невзначай.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov That's precisely how I understood it, and precisely what baffles me. With Slovak, one could debate. Czech, on the other hand, is about as far away from East Slavic phonetics as you get, down to its /t/'s and /d/'s being Germanic-like alveolars rather than dentals. I really don't think there's much room for subjectivity there, and I 'd have said the same thing, perhaps less confrontationally , had the claim been made by someone else. Thanks for the welcome!

Comment: Knowing both Belarussian and Polish I would say they are definitely not distant. Belarussian language got a lot from Polish due to historical reasons and therefore they share pretty large amount of similarities.

Answer (score 3):

Belarusian is, in a sense, in between other slavic languages.
Its grammar is close to that of Russian.
Its vocabulary has lots of common words with all of Russian, Ukrainian, and Polish, so it's sort of mutually intelligible with all of them.
Its spelling, however, is quite different from any of them. Also, it's probably the most phonetic of all, you can just read it as it's spelled and it will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Belarusian is an **East Slavic** language, the same as Russian and Ukrainian. Of all languages, *Ukrainian* is closest to Belarusian. Once you get used to Ukrainian pronunciation, you'll realize that they share a large part of vocabulary. Belarusian and Ukrainian haven't had such a profound impact of Church Slavonic as Russian had. Instead, they had more influence of Polish (language of shliachta) and German (via Yiddish and I guess Baltic port cities).

*Russian* will be the second closest. They share again a large part of vocabulary (Ukrainian does that too by the way), but again, the pronunciation is a bit different. From my experience, Russian speakers do not readily understand spoken Belarusian since around a third of words will be unknown to them.

The known words might have a different grammatical gender.
The prefixes, suffixes, personal pronouns are mostly the same (barring the pronunciation... you get the point).

Answer (score -2):

You see a lot of signs written in standard Belorussian.

As I understand, most of it was standardized in the early XX century, and the method was to try and pick words and word stems which sound unfamilliar to Russian ear. Otherwise written Belorussian would not be distinct enough from written Russian, and the goal was to set the language separate.

That explains why written Belorussian is more like Polish and less like Russian in its dictionary (compared to what its "natural speakers" would use) and why its spelling capitalizes its phonetic difference with Russian.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer is based on the idea that someone can construct written language and make people speak like that to create a new language ("spoiled Russian").

Comment: Belarusian was standardized in the 30s by the Soviets, and it almost killed the language, the method was to try and pick words and word stems which sound most familiar to Russian ear. Since then no world classics literature were printed in Belarusian.

Comment: @Artemix I'm unconvinced that people actually "speak like that" in Belorussian. However I'm not an expert.